# uploading and file validation with symfony

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony-1.4

I'm pretty new in Symfony, and I'm having a problem uploading a file

I just don't get it work, and I can't find something that tell me exactly how to use it or show me how it works (I had read smyfony official documentation)

this is my code:

the form

```
class PagosForm extends BasePagosForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array('file' => new sfWidgetFormInputFile()));

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('pagos[%s]');

    $this->setValidators(array('file' => new sfValidatorFile(array(
        'required'   => false
        ))));
  }
}
```

the actions

```
public function executeSelect(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
     $this->form = new PagosForm();
  }

 public function executeUpload(sfWebRequest $request)
  {

    $this->form = new PagosForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
      $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()), $request->getFiles($this->form->getName()));

      if ($this->form->isValid())
      {
        echo "isvalid";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      }
      else 
      {  
        echo "isinvalid";
        //echo var_dump($this->form);
      }
    }
  }
```

in select, there is outputed a button for selecting file and submit it:
that takes us to the action Upload.

selectSuccess.php

```
<?php echo form_tag('pagos/upload', 'enctype="multipart/form-data"', 'method="POST"') ?>
<?php echo $form['file'] ?>
<?php echo submit_tag('Send') ?>
```

I have some problems with eclipse, so I'm using Sublime text 2 (a text's editor) for coding, so its difficult for me find the errors.

I use `move_uploaded_file` because for some reason, I can't make it work the functions of symfony for uploading files. In this way, I can get it, but if I want to add some validation (for example, only allow to upload excel files), I can't get it work..

I always get line "isinvalid" printed, except I remove the line in the form that set validator. So, for some reason, the validator is not working..

I've tried to create my custom validator also, extending sfValidatorFile, but not working at all (I can't even upload any file or render the page)

So, I need a little help, before my head explodes (caused by symfony :P)

what is wrong with the code, that I always getting invalid file ? I'm trying to uploading a simple .txt of 3 KB, if I remove the valitadion, I can upload it normally

Comment: if you are new to symfony why not using symfony2 ? there is much more support for it

Comment: requeriments of the project :/ I can't choose on it

Comment: are the requirements use symfony1.4 ?

Comment: Yes, is an order that came from above. I do not choose this

Comment: ok :( can you post your validator code

Comment: I'm using the default validator right now (sfValidatorFile), and I'm always getting false in "isValid()"

Comment: First: you should use `<?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields() ?>` to render _csrf_token field (and other hidden input). Second: you should use `path` config value inside the sfValidatorFile to handle the `move_uploaded_file`.  Go [there](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/10?orm=Propel) and check the part about file upload (search for `sfWidgetFormInputFile`).

Comment: that's work !! renderHiddenFields I mean. If you post it as correct answer, I will check it

Comment: @Gonzalo.- wop sorry didn't see your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no one answer this, I will put it myself:

I needed to use `<?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields() ?>` to render _csrf_token field (and other hidden input).

with this, the validation has passed